# Border lines displayed in the repeating background image in the iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, css, background-image

I don't have a iPhone 6 Plus.

But I was pointed out the problem with the web site that I'm involved.

It was boundary lines displayed in the repeating background image in the iPhone 6 Plus.

The background image is png or gif.

Although the report of the similar problem is not found on a web, somebody else encountered this problem?

Is there any information whether it is a bug or not?

---

edit:

There is no problem in iPhone 6.

The size of the background image of CSS, I have specified in the half of the original.

Comment: Borders on the side of the Repeating image or borders around every copy of the original image in the repeating image?

Comment: Borders around every copy of the original image in the repeating image.